# Is it possible to scale the parent of an after/before pseudoelements without affecting the scale of the pseudoelements?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, pseudo-element

```
#ParentElement{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    background:white;
}

#ParentElement::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background: inherit;
}
```

If I have a trigger (Sibling of the Parent Element) that is supposed to scale the Parent Element.

```
#trigger + #ParentElement{
transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

How can I scale the Parent Element without affecting the scale of the pseudo element?

Comment: Hello, can you make a code snippet or sandbox on jsfiddle, codepen?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do on CodePen https://codepen.io/QualBean/pen/xxweZgP